# Android Studio unable to detect device when battery charge is above 92% and vibrates above 90%

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I am currently facing an unusual issue with Android Studio. Whenever my device's battery charge is above 92%, Android Studio fails to detect the device. Strangely, when the battery charge drops below 90%, the device becomes detectable again. Furthermore, above 90% charge, the phone starts vibrating whenever I hold it, which becomes quite distracting and hampers my productivity.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Device: Motorola moto g32
android version : 12
android studio : flamingo

I have attempted various troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue. Firstly, I tried restarting the phone, but unfortunately, the problem persisted. Next, I attempted to open the phone in safe mode, hoping that it would make a difference, but the device still couldn't be detected by Android Studio.

At my home, I usually use WiFi debugging, and it works perfectly fine. However, when I tried using the same setup at my workplace, WiFi debugging didn't work, even though both devices were connected to the same WiFi network.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.